# protractor, error geting the href value

Tags: jasmine, protractor

How can i get the href value per "a"?

```
<div class="nea-sidebar" _ngcontent-c2="">
<a class="sidebar-item active" href="#/test" _ngcontent-c2="" routerlinkactive="active" ng-reflect-router-link="test" ng-reflect-router-link-active="active">
<i class="sidebar-icon fas fa-play" _ngcontent-c2="" ng-reflect-klass="sidebar-icon fas" ng-reflect-ng-class="fa-play"></i>
<span class="sidebar-label" _ngcontent-c2="">Start Test</span></a>

<a class="sidebar-item" href="#/sequences" _ngcontent-c2="" routerlinkactive="active" ng-reflect-router-link="sequences" ng-reflect-router-link-active="active">
<i class="sidebar-icon fas fa-project-diagram" _ngcontent-c2="" ng-reflect-klass="sidebar-icon fas" ng-reflect-ng-class="fa-project-diagram"></i>
```

Sequences

I'm using:

```
element(by.css('nea-sidebar')).element(by.className('sidebar-item active')).isDisplayed().then (function(isVisible) {
if (isVisible) {
expect(element(by.css('nea-sidebar')).element(by.className('sidebar-item active')).getAttribute('href')).toBe('#/test');
}

});
```

It fails due to the "  - Expected " error:

> - Expected 'http://localhost:4200/#/test' to be '#/test'." to be '#/test'."

I think  that the return value is correct and i should change the ToBe condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getAttribute()` returns a promise. Try something like this:

```
element.all(by.css('.sidebaritem').first().getAttribute('href').then(function(value) { expect(value).toBe('#/test'); });
```

Comment: Your line returns:

 - Expected 'http://localhost:4200/#/test' to be '#/test'.

Should é change the toBe condition to include all URL?
I think the returned value is the corret  but the condition toBe is wrong.

Comment: try replacing .toBe with .toContain